# C++ similar behavior to java.lang.Enum<E>

Tags: c++, enumeration

Does c++ or the STL support the function [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) within `java.lang.Enum<e>` such that it enables

```
elements = Syntax.valueOf(temp);

switch(elements) {}
```

and whereby `elements` is of type `enum` and `temp` is of type String?

Comment: Since this question has already gotten 3 upvotes and no 100k+rep C++ people answered it, I suppose the answer is "no" within a 95% level of certainty.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask how [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) could be implemented in c++ so as to enable such functionality?

Comment: The problem with this is that during semantic analysis, the names of the enum members are discareded. Only the parser could tell you about a certain value what its name was.